# Validar login do usuário

Tags: jsf, hibernate

Eu não estou conseguindo validar o login do usuário. Alguém me poderia da uma ajuda?

O meu Dao:

```
public Login getvalidarLogin(Login login ){

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
    try{
        Query query = session.createQuery("from login where login_login='"+login.getLogin_login()+"' and login_senha='"+login.getLogin_senha()+"'");
        login = (Login)query.uniqueResult();
        t.commit();

    }catch(HibernateException e){
        System.out.println("ERRO AO VALIDAR LOGIN .Erro: >>>>>>" + e.getMessage());
    }
    return login;
}
```

O meu Bean:

```
public String validacaoLogin(){

    login = dao.getvalidarLogin(login);
    if(login != null){
        login = new Login();
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Usuário não encontrado!","Erro no Login!"));
        return null;
    } else {
            return "medico/medicoView";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Está dando alguma exceção?

Comment: select
        login0_.id_login as id1_16_,
        login0_.login_login as login2_16_,
        login0_.login_senha as login3_16_,
        login0_.tipo_usuario as tipo4_16_ 
    from
        login login0_ 
    where
        login0_.login_login='farmacia' 
        and login0_.login_senha='123'
out 13, 2015 10:53:18 AM com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitUtils renderUnhandledMessages
INFORMAÇÕES: AVISO: FacesMessage(s) foram enfileirados, mas podem não ter sido exibidos.
sourceId=null[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(UsuÃ¡rio nÃ£o encontrado!), detail=(Erro no Login!)]